# matplotlib how to show plot when not in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am working with a legacy codebase that uses python modules together with jupyter notebook. The plotting functionality is contained in the python modules eg:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class SomeClass(object):
    def plot(self, x_data, y_data)
        plt.plot(x_data, y_data)
        #I added this code to show plot if not using notebook
        plt.show()
```

I would rather not add ply.show() to all the places in the legacy code where pyplot is used.

Is there a global way to 'force' pyplot to show when get_ipython() is not in the global context?

Comment: You could save it as an image and open it with `os.system("open filename.png")`

Comment: This is not clear. How should the program know at which point to show something other than you specifying `plt.show()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work in interactive mode, plot is shown directly. You turn on interactive mode by calling `plt.ion()` once. Thus you still have to modify your legacy code, by adding this command, but that needs only to be done once, in the beginning of the program.